# IntelliJ Node.js debug process exit -1

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea

I've setup a project in IntelliJ 13 to run my nodeJS app. It runs fine. The problem is I can't use the debugger. When I try to run in debug mode the console prints

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=50839 --debug app.js
debugger listening on port 50839

Process finished with exit code -1
```

The console tab displays "Process disconnected unexpectedly"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with debug mode ("Process finished with exit code -1073741510")
The problem was solved when I removed old watches from watch list. Debugger seems to be sensitive to those garbage watches.

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic error that doesn't really provide any meaningful information.

I had the same issue today on Mac OSX and I finally discovered it was a combination of the new-relic package with "Break on Exception" option enabled that crashed the node app each time I started the debugger.

I hope this helps.